# FreeRADIUS - how to create a profile for two differnet NAS

Tags: freeradius

how i can create a profile for two different NAS (Cisco & MicroTek) with different attributes.

i don't know if there is a way to make if statement depend on the IP of NAS or not.

for more explanation:

i use daloradius to manage the freeradius,  i can't manage the speed because now i have for example 10M profile with attribute Cisco-AVPair=ip:sub-qos-policy-in=10Mbps but in MikroTek is different it used Mikrotik-Rate-Limit=10M so i need one profile treat with both if the user connect to the cisco will use his policymap and when he connect to MikroTek use the other attribute

Comment: Could you please provide more information, such as any code you have written so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can define arbitrary attributes associated with a NAS in `clients.conf`

For example:

```
client 192.168.0.1 {
    secret = testing123
    my_attribute = 'foo'
}
```

Then access them with the `%{client:<attribute>}` xlat.

```
authorize {
    update reply {
        Reply-Message := "User connecting to NAS with attribute %{client:my_attribute}"
    }
}
```

This is significantly more efficient that huntgroups or the other grouping mechanisms.